# How to add methods dynamically

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to add methods dynamically from external files.
Right now I have `__call` method in my class so when i call the method I want, `__call` includes it for me; the problem is I want to call loaded function by using my class, and I don't want loaded function outside of the class;

```
Class myClass
{
    function__call($name, $args)
    {
        require_once($name.".php");
    }
}
```

echoA.php:

```
function echoA()
{
    echo("A");
}
```

then i want to use it like:

```
$myClass = new myClass();
$myClass->echoA();
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: From the php [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/functions.user-defined.php): *"...All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope..."*. So at least: *"...and I don't want loaded function outside of the class;..."* will not be possible.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @Yoshi i think i didn't explained well, when i include the file that contains the function, it can be called anywhere, like: echoA(); instead of $myClass->echoA();

Comment: PHP is not Ruby. Once class is defined, you can't really add methods to it.

Answer (score 19):

Is this what you need?

```
$methodOne = function ()
{
    echo "I am  doing one.".PHP_EOL;
};

$methodTwo = function ()
{
    echo "I am doing two.".PHP_EOL;
};

class Composite
{
    function addMethod($name, $method)
    {
        $this->{$name} = $method;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func($this->{$name}, $arguments);
    }
}


$one = new Composite();
$one -> addMethod("method1", $methodOne);
$one -> method1();
$one -> addMethod("method2", $methodTwo);
$one -> method2();
```

Comment: Thank you, the `_call` method is exactly what was missing for me!

Answer (score 14):

You cannot dynamically add methods to a class at runtime, period.*
PHP simply isn't a very [duck-punchable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_punching) language.

<sub>* Without [ugly hacks](http://www.php.net/runkit).</sub>

Comment: what about this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-method-add.php.is it possible to use this technique to dynamically add methods?

Comment: Yeah, I linked to something very similar in my answer. It's still a hack.

Comment: It's great that Pavel just duck punched you with an answer

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically add attributes and methods providing it is done through the constructor in the same way you can pass a function as argument of another function.

```
class Example {
    function __construct($f)
    {
       $this->action=$f;
    }
}

function fun() {
   echo "hello\n";
}

$ex1 = new class('fun');
```

You can not call directlry `$ex1->action()`, it must be assigned to a variable and then you can call this variable like a function.

Comment: Please post an essential part here

Comment: This don't works, you get error that there are no `Example::action` function.

Answer (score 3):

if i read the manual right,
the __call get called **insted** of the function, if the function dosn't exist
so you probely need to call it after you created it

```
Class myClass
{
    function __call($name, $args)
    {
        require_once($name.".php");
        $this->$name($args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add methods to php classes while execution.

Comment: i tried this 2hours ago, we cant add method by including a file that contains function(s), that's why i asked this question ;)

Comment: I think this could be the valid answer, besides the require_once way to call the dynamic function does not seem the way to go. I'm creating a method on the fly conditionally using the __call magic method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called *Overloading*. Read all about it in the [**PHP Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute in your class : `methods=[]`
and use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) for create lambda function.
Stock it in the `methods` attribute, at index of the name of method you want.
use :

```
function __call($method, $arguments)
{
   if(method_exists($this, $method))
      $this->$method($arguments);
   else
      $this->methods[$method]($arguments);
}
```

to find and call good method.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @method Talk hello(string $name)
 * @method Talk goodbye(string $name)
 */
class Talk {
    private $methods = [];
    
    public function __construct(array $methods) {
        $this->methods = $methods;
    }
    
    public function __call(string $method, array $arguments): Talk {
        if ($func = $this->methods[$method] ?? false) {
            $func(...$arguments);
            
            return $this;
        }
        
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Missing %s method.'));
    }
}

$howdy = new Talk([
    'hello' => function(string $name) {
        echo sprintf('Hello %s!%s', $name, PHP_EOL);
    },
    'goodbye' => function(string $name) {
        echo sprintf('Goodbye %s!%s', $name, PHP_EOL);
    },
]);

$howdy
    ->hello('Jim')
    ->goodbye('Joe');
```

https://3v4l.org/iIhph

Answer (score 0):

You can do both adding methods and properties dynamically.

Properties:

```
class XXX
{
    public function __construct($array1)
    {
        foreach ($array1 as $item) {
            $this->$item = "PropValue for property : " . $item;
        }
    }
}

$a1 = array("prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop4");
$class1 = new XXX($a1);
echo $class1->prop1 . PHP_EOL;
echo $class1->prop2 . PHP_EOL;
echo $class1->prop3 . PHP_EOL;
echo $class1->prop4 . PHP_EOL;
```

Methods:

```
//using anonymous function
$method1 = function () {
    echo "this can be in an include file and read inline." . PHP_EOL;
};

class class1
{
    //build the new method from the constructor, not required to do it here but it is simpler.
    public function __construct($functionName, $body)
    {
        $this->{$functionName} = $body;
    }

    public function __call($functionName, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func($this->{$functionName}, $arguments);
    }
}

//pass the new  method name and the refernce to the anounymous function
$myObjectWithNewMethod = new class1("method1", $method1);
$myObjectWithNewMethod->method1();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/closure.call.php) will help you.

UPD:
Yes, guys, I was wrong. Even we convert named function to closure, there will be [error of binding context.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) I did not pay attention that TS has ready external functions. But my link can be useful for those peoples, who get here after googled how to call SOME THEIR code inside class's instance's scope. I used myself Reflection to do this until met and tried Closure.

Comment: Could you edit this post to say why it might help in the situation presented?

Comment: show how it can help?

Answer (score -3):

I've worked up the following code example and a helper method which works with `__call` which may prove useful. https://github.com/permanenttourist/helpers/tree/master/PHP/php_append_methods

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.