# How can I dynamically add a method to a class?

Tags: php

I know I can dynamically add properties, at runtime, to a PHP class (see example below).
But I can't find a way to add a ***method*** to a class at runtime.
What I've tried so far:

```
    class Test {  

            public $name;  

            public function __construct($name){  
                $this->name=$name;  
            }  

            public function addProperty($name,$value){  
                $this->$name=$value;  
            }  

            public function addMethod($name, $value) {  
                 $this->$name=$value;  
            }  

    }  


    $t=new Test("Morris");  
    echo $t->name .'<br>'; // => "Morris"  
    echo $t->firstname .'<br>'; // as expected => "Notice: Undefined property: Test::$firstname"  

    $t->addProperty("firstname","John"); // dynamically add new property  
    echo $t->firstname .'<br>'; // => "John" (property has definitely been added).

    $f=function($i){return $i*$i;};  
    echo $f(7); // ==> 49  

    $t->addMethod("square",$f); // trying to dynamically add a new method  
    echo $t->square(4); // expected: 46, but..... => "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Test::square()"
```

This doesn't work.
Is there something more I should do in `addMethod()` ?
Or some magic class-method which should be overriden ?
Is it possible at all ?

Comment: Check magic methods in PHP __call() and __callStatic() [PHP Magic Methods](https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/16-php-magic-methods.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add methods dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026487/how-to-add-methods-dynamically)

Comment: @imvain2 It would, if there was an accepted answer, and if the accepted answer was not the one that tells it's not possible (the most upvoted one) :-( So I'll accept Akash prajapati's answer below, and you'll see if it has to be closed as duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below code

```
class Foo
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->$method)) {
            $func = $this->$method;
            return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = function () { echo "Hello, this function is added at runtime"; };
$foo->bar();
```

Comment: @imvain2 This answer helped me as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029975/3872061, thanks. @Akash: the ```if(isset(...))``` is a bad idea in my case, if a situation came where the property was called without having been added, I prefer a catched exception than no execution without any warning.